# Gradle 3.0.0-beta1 build issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I just updated the gradle version to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
```

after updating android studio to 3.0-beta1, and my gradle-wrapper is:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

the problem is I'm facing this weird issue when I want to Gradle-sync the project:

```
Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(UnixPath.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutput.getOutputPath(BuildOutput.java:222)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.lambda$load$2(BuildOutputs.java:243)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:245)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:184)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:140)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.lambda$get$1(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:55)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:50)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:35)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.AndroidArtifactImpl.getOutputs(AndroidArtifactImpl.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:592)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$AdaptingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:397)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$PropertyCachingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:625)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SafeMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:647)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SupportedPropertyInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:670)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:356)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy204.getOutputs(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.java:57)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.lambda$new$1(IdeVariantImpl.java:63)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:74)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.<init>(IdeVariantImpl.java:62)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.lambda$new$4(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:88)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:74)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:87)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:68)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.<init>(AndroidModuleModel.java:131)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:214)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:103)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:902)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've checked everything and they all look fine, can anyone help?

Comment: Same here, any temporary fix on this as of now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Build -> Clean project`, then

```
Build -> Rebuild project
```

Answer (score 3):

As per this **official** [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) this is known issue.

> ***Known issue***: If you have an existing Android Studio project that's
>   using an alpha version of Android plugin 3.0.0 (such as 3.0.0-alpha9),
>   you may get the following error when you migrate to Android plugin
>   3.0.0-beta1 and [sync your project](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#sync-files): *Gradle project refresh failed.*
>
> ***Solution***: Resolve this issue by selecting **Build > Clean Project** from the menu
>   bar—you need to perform this action only once for each project. You
>   can then sync your project files with Gradle by clicking **Sync Project**
>   from the menu bar.

Answer (score 2):

Try this option:

1. Leave the Gradle Sync error as is and clean the project
2. Rebuild the project
3. Now Sync the Gradle now

***Note:*** I also did

> invalidate and restart

before trying this out

It helped me, hope it helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known bugs in 3.0.0, This issue is one it, actually android studio is integrating Unix file system (Berkeley Fast File System) for Linux OS and it is in beta....Please downgrade your studio to 2.3.3 stable version for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue after the updating to **beta1**.
Try to update your build tools to the latest version in SDK Manager -> SDK Tools. Then add the google maven to your **root build.gradle** like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

This worked in my case properly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to upgrade to 3.0.0-beta1 on Linux Mint 18.1. Nothing of the above helped: neither Clean -> Rebuild -> Sync, nor Invalidate & Restart. But Sanat's suggestion of downgrading to 2.3.3 helped